# Trying to prove that $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'\cong\Bbb R^\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism, dual-spaces

> Prove that $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ and $\Bbb R^\infty$ are isomorphic vector spaces.

Here $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ is the dual space of the vector space of polynomial functions with real coefficients $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$. And $\Bbb R^\infty$ is the set of all real valued sequences.

This is the exercise 35 in page 132 of *Linear algebra done right, 3rd edition*.

The problem here is that the book at this point only teach, in almost all cases, the theory of linear algebra of finite dimensional vector spaces, but $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is not finite dimensional.

My work, at the moment, is below.

---

Define $B_k(p):=\frac{p^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=[x^k]p(x)$ for $p\in\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, where $p^{(k)}$ is the $k$-th derivative of $p$. Then the set defined by

$$B:=\{B_k:k\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}\}\tag{1}$$

is linearly independent in $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$, however it is not a basis because functionals defined as

$$p\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kB_k(p),\quad c_k\in\Bbb R\tag{2}$$

belong also to $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ but they arent a linear combination of $B_k$ because the above sum is not finite.

It is easy to see that any functional with the form in $(2)$ define a vector subspace $S$ of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ and the map defined by

$$h: S\to \Bbb R^\infty,\quad\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kB_k\mapsto (c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_k,\ldots)$$

is linear and bijective. Then if we show that $S=\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ we are done.

Because every polynomial is a linear combination of monomials we can study all the elements of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ just studying the form of all possible linear functionals for monomials of the kind $x^k$.

For finite vector spaces $\mathcal P_m(\Bbb R)$, defined as the vector space of polynomial functions of degree at most $m$, we know that the set

$$H_m:=\{B_k:k\in\{0,\ldots,m\}\}$$

is a basis of $\mathcal P_m(\Bbb R)'$.

But Im stuck here: my main problem is that I dont know if I can prove (and how, if it would be possible) that $S=\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ from the finite case, that is that all the functionals of $\mathcal P_m(\Bbb R)'$ have the form

$$p\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^m c_kB_k(p),\quad c_k\in\Bbb R,p\in\mathcal P_m(\Bbb R)$$

Probably the way Im trying to prove the statement of the exercise is a dead end, but the theory in the book dont show complicated proofs or theorems, so it cannot be so complicate. Some hints will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think trying to work with a basis in $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)'$ is going to be a bad idea - bases of many infinite dimensional vector spaces, $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)'$ included, are impossible to right down. Thankfully, a basis of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ *can* be written down: for each $k\in\mathbb N$ (including zero), let $e_k(x):=x^k$; then $\{e_k\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$. In particular, any linear functional is determined uniquely by its action on $\{e_k\}$. This turns out to be a better method.

For any sequence $a=(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$, let $\phi_a$ be the unique linear functional on $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ such that $\phi_a(e_k)=a_k$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$. I claim $\Phi:a\mapsto\phi_a$ is a linear isomoprhism. That $\Phi$ is linear is easy to prove. If $\phi_a=0$, then $\phi_a(e_k)=0$ for every $k$, i.e. $a_k=0$ for all $k$, so $a=0$. This shows $\Phi$ is injective. Now let $\psi\in\mathcal P(\mathbb R)'$ be any linear functional. Define $a_k:=\psi(e_k)$. By definition $\psi=\phi_a$. This shows $\Phi$ is surjective, completing the proof.

Note: the notation $\mathbb R^\infty$ is not standard, and in fact some authors use it to refer to the space of sequences for which only finitely many entries are non-zero. (This space is actually isomorphic to $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ - can you prove it?) Writing $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ is more standard, and is a special case of the general notation $X^Y:=\{\text{functions }f:Y\to X\}$.

Comment: Yes, I generally use the notation $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ but Im following the notation of the book. I will need some time to digest the answer completely.

Comment: I think I get it. Indeed we can define each linear functional $\phi_a$ by a series of the form of $(2)$ in my question, right?

Comment: Well... as written, $B_k$ maps $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ to itself. If you instead take $B_k(p)=\frac{p^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$, then $B_k(p)$ is simply the coefficient of $x^k$ in $p$, so something like that should work.

Comment: I had a typo in the original text, yes $B_k(p):=[x^k]p(x)$. I had written my own answer completing the path of my question.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ has basis $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n,\dots\}$. Since any linear functional in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})'$ is determined completely by its action on the basis, we may construct an injective linear map from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})'$ to $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ via the assignment $$\ell \mapsto (\ell(x^n))_{n=0}^\infty$$ Surjectivity is also quick to see.

Comment: what means $\ell(x^n)$? The concept of action is not shown in this book (at this moment).

Comment: The phrase "its action on" may be replaced with "what it does to". By $\ell(x^n)$ I mean the real number one gets when applying a linear functional $\ell$ to $x^n$.

Comment: I see but, how you knows that the map is surjective? It is hard to imagine that for each real valued sequence exists a linear functional $\ell$ that with the map $(\ell(x^n))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ define this sequence.

Comment: Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be any real valued sequence. Now define $\ell$ on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ by $\ell(x^n) = a_n$ for all $n$. By defining $\ell$ on the basis we have actually defined it everywhere: any polynomial in our space may be written $p = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j x^j$ for some real scalars $\lambda_j$. We may force linearity of $\ell$ by setting $\ell(p) =  \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j a_j$.

Comment: @Masacroso The map he means is a bijection is the map that associates to each linear functional $\ell$ the sequence $(\ell(x^{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I will add my own solution to complete the path of my question (based in the previous answers).

---

Any possible functional $f_{c,k}$ over $x^k$ can be written as

$$f_{c,k}(x^k)=c\tag{3}$$

for any $c\in\Bbb R$. But observe that if we define $$f_{c,k}(x^k):=c B_k(x^k)$$

then the $f_{c,k}$ are linear, and because $\{x^k:k\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ then any functional of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$ have the form in $(2)$, hence $S=\mathcal P(\Bbb R)'$.$\Box$